# SQL Server hosting Kentico DB has high CPU

Tags: sql-server, cpu-usage, kentico

I am a DBA.  I see that the SQL instance on the dedicated server has an average 50% CPU being consumed and all by the SQL server. There are few queries which have very high CPU usage. I have looked from a DBA perspective and havent got any solution. Is there a known Kentico solution/setting for this?

Thanks.

Comment: `There are few queries which have very high CPU usage` you may need to tune them

Comment: What version of Kentico is this?

Comment: I would also recommend checking what is triggering the SQL queries - some steps leading to this. You can also check the [SQL debug][1] in Kentico to see what pages and components are triggering those queries.


  [1]: https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/troubleshooting-websites/debugging#Debugging-SQLqueries

Comment: What @jurajo says and then update the question with the queries, please...